# 入社 equivalent for a research internship

Tags: words, business-japanese

When writing in some formal Japanese CV (学歴/職歴), it is common to be asked to put each job/university/etc. on a single dated line, with a second line to indicate when one quit/graduated/dropped-out/etc. E.g:

> 平成２０年　４月　１日　　東京大学情報学部**入学**
>
> 平成２４年　３月３１日　　同上**卒業**
>
> 平成２４年　４月　１日　　松下電器産業株式会社**入社**

etc.

University enrollment will be 入学/卒業, post-grad would be 進学/卒業, job would be 入社/退社...

My question is then:

**What is a proper equivalent to indicate *a research internship*?**

That is a non-paying, temporary research position in a public (government-run) lab facility that is *not* a university (国立研究所). In such a case, it seems that both 入社 and 入学 would not fit. 入所 sounds like it *might* be a possibility, but also may be a complete mistranslation (since the word also exists for completely different situations).

I would welcome any suggestions, (preferably) with pointers to approved examples or other authoritative sources...

Comment: According to web search, it seems that entering a non-corporate lab with the name 研究所 is usually called 入所 in a CV.  However, I may not write a non-paid research internship in either 学歴 or 職歴 if there is any other way to state it in the CV.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto If some position fits neither 学歴 (academic carrier with degrees) nor 職歴 (paid job carrier), then it may be put under 経歴 (carrier).

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: thanks. My cursory Google search had not found anything conclusive. If you don't mind quoting some of the examples you found in an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Regarding your point about 学歴/職歴: you are absolutely right, and there is actually a third section '研究歴' for that (I didn't want to go into too many irrelevant details in my question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question (after receiving the answer from somewhere else at the time), the proper term would be: **滞在開始**.

E.g.:

> 平成２４年　３月０１日　松下電器産業株式会社にインターンシッププログラムにより滞在開始
>
> 平成２４年　３月３１日　同上卒業

Comment: Is that true?  滞在 (staying) sounds quite different from internship.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: this is what I was recommended by one of my advisors. Considering it is a stay (without pay), it does make sense to me. Note that the 'internship' part is also mentioned in the phrase.

Comment: 滞在する is usually used with a place, not with an organization, and I do not think that we usually say ○○株式会社に滞在する.  So ○○株式会社にインターンシッププログラムにより滞在開始 sounds quite odd to me.  But I am not very familiar with Japanese in business, and if that is really correct, I have no objection to it.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: well, I can't guarantee it is correct (otherwise I wouldn't have been asking in the first place). I can only guarantee it is coming from a person who ought to know (having both research and business experience). That being said: he might be wrong and in that case, hopefully someone will come along with some new input at some point.

Answer (score 4):

平成20年4月1日　・・・・インターンシップ（　・・・・研修）　**開始**

平成21年3月31日　同上　**終了**

Comment: That seems like it would work :)